# Assigning values to a dataframe by iterating through two lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of meaning housing prices by month that looks like this

```
RegionName    2000-01    2000-02    2000-03  

New York      200000     210000     220000
Austin        100000     110000     130000  ...
Los Angeles   180000     190000     200000
```

I have a list of lists of months corresponding to quarters and a list of quarters that look like

```
month_chunks = [['2000-01', '2000-02', '2000-03'], ['2000-04', '2000-05', '2000-06']...]

quarters = ['2000q1', '2000q2', '2000q3'...]
```

I'm trying to create columns in my dataframe that contain mean prices by quarter

```
for quarter, chunk in zip(quarters, month_chunks):
        housing[quarter] = np.mean(housing[chunk].mean())

RegionName    2000-01    2000-02    2000-03       2000q1   

New York      200000     210000     220000        210000    
Austin        100000     110000     130000  ...   113333.333 
Los Angeles   180000     190000     200000        190000
```

But it is giving me columns that are duplicated for each row

```
RegionName    2000-01    2000-02    2000-03       2000q1   

New York      200000     210000     220000        210000    
Austin        100000     110000     130000  ...   210000 
Los Angeles   180000     190000     200000        210000
```

The dataframe is large, so iterating through it and the lists is not doable

```
for i, row in housing.iterrows():
    for quarter, chunk in zip(quarters, month_chunks):
        row[quarter].iloc[i] = np.mean(row[chunk].iloc[i].mean())
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't `iterrows`, you can perform your operation columns wise:

```
for months, qt in zip(month_chunks, quarters):
    housing[qt] = housing[months].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: You're welcome. And please don't forget to upvote/accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `groupby`

```
from collections import ChainMap
d=dict(ChainMap(*[dict.fromkeys(x,y)for x , y in zip(month_chunks,quarters)]))
s=housing.set_index('RegionName').groupby(d,axis=1).mean()
s
Out[32]: 
                   2000q1
RegionName               
NewYork     210000.000000
Austin      113333.333333
LosAngeles  190000.000000

df=pd.concat([housing.set_index('RegionName'),s],axis=1)
```